# Jquery onkeyup or onchange function depending on value in HTML Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange, keyup

I have three field **amount**, **amount with tax**, and **tax (%)**, when a user enter **%** amount it automatic calculated through keyUp event function. Problems arise when a user round up the **amount with tax** value and again go through to submit by pressing **TAB** key. it detects Keyup event and changes the value to initial value. guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: What do you mean? The user will first put the tax % and then the other textbox will automatically have a value?

Comment: User first enter the amount, and then enter tax %

Comment: @ThataL can you insert your code too

Comment: _"Problems arise when a user round up the amount with tax value"_ why are you allowing the user to update the amount with tax value, your application should be calculating that.

Comment: some times invoice comes with round value and my system also need to round that value as invoice.

Comment: Please have a look the real form how it calculates. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/q6o7h5f4/1/)

Comment: My code example here [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7atnzvdw/13/) input as amount= 109.66, tax%= 18, tax amount round to 20 and total should be 129.66

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice that if you want to achieve what you looking for which is by rounding up the **tax amount** the **tax** field will also update because of the `onkeyup` event you applied which means this has became something like a chaining event. I have apply some changes in the code to trigger the value of the tax field once the user intend to manually change the tax amount like below :

```
calculateTotal = function(){
   var total = 0.00;
   var amount = $("#amount").val();
   var amount_with_tax = $("#amount_with_tax").val();
   amount = parseFloat(amount);
   amount_with_tax = parseFloat(amount_with_tax);
   total = amount + amount_with_tax;
   var tax = (100-(amount/total)*100).toFixed(2);
   console.log(total);
   $('#tax').val(tax);
   $('#total').text(total.toFixed(2));
}
```

Please also note that in such case `onkeyup` event is not a good event listener because the functions are both *linking* in a way that the fields value are **dependent**. So I change the event listener to `onchange` which will only trigger the event only if the users focus in or out of the input fields.

Comment: Thanks for your guide. But I wanted to show user real-time calculation hence I used onkeyup and for OnChange event a issue arise. if a user change the value but changeEvent not occured that time and direct click to submit button. then the value passed to POST is the previous value not the current one.

Comment: I have tested here OnChange Event [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7atnzvdw/32/) worked fine.

Comment: @ThataL onchange will work because it will fire whenever focus or lose focus on the fields